# class << notation in modules

Tags: ruby, module, metaprogramming, mixins

I'm trying to mix a module into a class, and I want some of the methods to behave as class methods and others to be instance methods.

However, I don't want to both `include` *and* `extend` the module.  I'd rather just `include` it.

When I wrap the methods I want to be class methods in this notation, it works:

```
class <<
  # ...
end
```

However, when I use this notation it doesn't work:

```
class << self
  # ...
end
```

I suspect the `self` keyword is establishing an explicit binding to the module, rather than the class it gets mixed into.  But I've not seen any documentation that recommends leaving the `self` keyword off when using the `class <<` notation.

Does anyone know what's going on with this?

---

**UPDATE: Here's some sample code for more clarity:**

```
module M
  class <<
    def class_method
      puts "From inside the class_method"
    end
  end

  def instance_method
    puts "From inside the instance_method"
  end
end

class Object
  include M
end

class C
end


C.class_method

obj = C.new
obj.instance_method
```

Comment: Huh, did I miss something? `class << end` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`class <<` must always be followed by an object. Just `class <<; end` is a syntax error. In your case it looks like it works because of the following:

```
class <<
  def class_method
    puts "From inside the class_method"
  end
end
```

is the same as

```
class << def class_method
    puts "From inside the class_method"
  end
end
```

which is the same as

```
temp = def class_method
  puts "From inside the class_method"
end
class << temp
end
```

which is the same as

```
def class_method
  puts "From inside the class_method"
end
class << nil
end
```

which is the same as

```
def class_method
  puts "From inside the class_method"
end
```

Of course that doesn't actually define a class method. It defines an instance method.

Comment: Lol.  That explains why the "apparent" class method needed to be in Object to work. It was actually a singleton instance method.  Nice work.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, if you want to get a real `self` in your module you should use `included` [callback](http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/included). Something like this point you in the right direction:

```
module Bar
  def self.included(base)
    class << base
      def class_method
        "class_method"
      end
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include Bar
end


p Foo.class_method # => "class_method"
```

Comment: I believe this is what he wants to actually solve his problem, but it doesn't answer the actual question of what `class <<` is doing compared to `class << self`.

Comment: like @sepp2k said `class << end` is a syntax error. So I actually don't know what Nathan means :(

Comment: Thanks nash, I know about the included method, but discovered that leaving the self off seems to achieve a similar effect.  I'm not getting a syntax error, and have tried in ruby 1.8 and 1.9.3 -- I'll post a complete code sample in a bit for others to try.

Comment: I'm using 1.9.2 and I can reproduce Nathan's problem.  If I use `class <<`, followed by at least one method (on a new line) followed by `end`, I don't get the syntax error.  But then again, if I put them all on one line with semicolons, I *do* get the syntax error.  It's very weird...

Comment: @ChrisRice When you do `class <<` followed by a method def, the def is taken as the operand to `<<`. I.e. you define the method first and then basically do `class << nil` aftterwards (because `def` returns `nil`).

Comment: One detail that I didn't notice until just now, I'm including the module into Object.  Otherwise, I am getting a NoMethodErrror.  Anyway, I posted a sample of the code up top.

Comment: @sepp2k I didn't realize that would work across the newline.  Thanks for clarifying. :)